# A question erroneously labeled as duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicates

A question was submitted by [user929304](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/62173/user929304) titled:
[Balance of a spinning coin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492105/17198)

This question is about the case of rolling motion, as in, for instance, rolling down an incline. So you see a coin rolling over, say, the floor of a corridor, and it just keeps going.

Another case is the one of a coin that isn't going anywhere; it is made to spin in place.

Those are distinct cases, yet John Rennie and Qmechanic have closed the question about a rolling coin, labeling it as duplicate of the spinning-in-place case.

I don't have enough reputation points yet to submit this for reversal of the mislabeling, so I'm reporting it here.

(I noticed the mislabeling because I had written an answer)

Comment: Some general advice -- if a question is marked as duplicate and it shouldn't be, it is likely because something in your question was not clear enough to make it obviously distinct from the suggested duplicate. So, take the opportunity to edit your question to clarify it so there cannot be any misunderstandings. A side benefit -- doing this will put it into a review queue so it could be reopened.

Comment: Re: your edit -- you can still suggest/make an edit that makes the question clearer, even if it's not yours. You have >2000 rep, so the edit is automatically approved. It will still put it into the review queue.

Comment: @tpg2114 The question was not submitted by me. I just happened to notice the mislabeling. I have edited the question to state explicitly who submitted the question

Answer (score 8):

Changed the title from *Balance of a spinning coin* to *Balance of a rolling coin,* and reopened question.